# Using a Wildcard or Regex in OnMarkerEvaluator filter

Tags: logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I'm trying to write an appender that accepts all Markers from `logstash-logback-encoder`

I've tried the following using logback `1.0.7` and `logstash-logback-encoder` `4.6`

```
<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
            <!-- Accept only Markers from logstash-logback-encoder -->
            <marker>LS_*</marker>                
        </evaluator>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
```

....

However it doesn't work. Nothing seems to enter this appender.

The following filter work bit is quite cumbersome

```
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
        <!-- Accepts only Markers from logstash-logback-encoder -->
        <marker>LS_MAP_FIELDS</marker>
        <marker>LS_OBJECT_FIELDS</marker>
        <marker>LS_APPEND_</marker>
        <marker>LS_APPEND_OBJECT</marker>
        <marker>LS_APPEND_RAW</marker>
    </evaluator>
```

Answer (score 1):

With reference to code for [OnMarkerEvaluation](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/boolex/OnMarkerEvaluator.java) its not possible achieve wildcard or regex match with its current implementation.
But an alternate solution is to implement your own EventEvaluatorBase like below :

```
package com.test;

import org.slf4j.Marker;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.EvaluationException;
import ch.qos.logback.core.boolex.EventEvaluatorBase;

public class CustomEvaluator extends EventEvaluatorBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    public boolean evaluate(ILoggingEvent event) throws NullPointerException, EvaluationException {
        Marker eventsMarker = event.getMarker();
        return eventsMarker.getName().startsWith("LS_");
    }

}
```

This is just an example for your specific case, can be customized and generalized further.